# Python GPIO list for loop, but dont wait for finish

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gpio

On my Raspberry im using GPIO ports to switch some lights on and off.
So in Python i made a list of jobs where a `job` has a duration and a port.

so the very basic script would be something like this:

```
def do_jobs(jobs):
    for job in jobs:
        do_work(job)

def do_work(job):
    try:
        duration = int(job.Duration)
        gpioPort = int(job.Port)
        logger.debug(f'Setting GPIO mode to BCM')
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(gpioPort, GPIO.OUT)
        logger.info(f'Turning ON GPIO port {gpioPort} for a duration of {duration} seconds')
        GPIO.output(job, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(duration)
        logger.info(f'Turning OFF GPIO port {gpioPort}')
        GPIO.output(item, GPIO.LOW)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Unexpected error:" + str(e))
    finally:
        logger.info(f'Cleaning up GPIO ports!')
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Theoretically, in this list of jobs, there could be multiple jobs that need to start at the same time, or with a few minutes difference; for example a multiple light should switch on at the same time, or the first has a duration of 1 hour and starts at 20:00 but the next wants to start at 20:05 for an hour.

The issue that im running into here would be that the list of jobs, would call the `do_work` function and then waits till its finished.
Is there some way to let it call the `do_work` function, but then proceed to the next item in the list, without waiting for the other do_work instance to finish ?

Comment: You will need a completely different design. How will jobs ensure that they start at the right time of day?

Comment: @quamrana that part is handled prior to this code sample; the result of the date and time checks is output in the jobs list, so i know those are the jobs that need to execute at a given time (now). as mentioned there could be multiple light bulbs that need to be turned on at the same date and time (seconds would be neglectable )

Comment: You're looking for `threads` to execute concurrent tasks, take a look at `threadpool`

Comment: Maybe when each job is generated initially, it should be added to your collection as *two* jobs. The first for the turn-on, the second for the turn-off. So each job only has a time of day action time, port number, on or off action, but no duration.